# What information does 'timing.entries' section gives in Lighthouse report?

Tags: lighthouse

For example, if I have to get Redirect Time, I have two options - 1) Audits 2) Timing.entries.

From Audits

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inawp.png)

2. From Timing.entries [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5X49.png)

The Lighthouse documentation specifies that the Timing.entries is a log of events during the test and logs the time spent by Lighthouse on evaluating the metric. So in the above example, is 859Ms the value for Redirect Time and 8.8s is the time spent by Lighthouse in evaluating the Redirect Time?